# Magento 2 - Set flat shipping price independent of currency

Tags: magento2, shipping, currency, multicurrency

**USD** is the base currency in my store. However, I'm in need of setting a flat shipping rate in a different currency.

And, if I do a conversion of shipping rate to work in USD, every time I set a different conversion rate it'll vary, which is not what I intend to do.

How can I set a "hardcoded" shipping rate that doesn't take into account base currency and calculates shipping rate in different currency, making checkout calculation correct?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Well you could do it the hard way with rewrites to skip conversion or by hardcoded setting the base_shipping, but you also could do it the lazy quick and dirty way with different stores.

Let's say we got

store1 is USD with base currency USD in stores > configuration > general > currency setup (for default store) and 
store2 is EUR with base currency EUR for this store only

Then set a default and a per store flat rate price.

Would this work for you?

Comment: Thanks, ended up with a module that adds a custom shipping method, from there takes currency rate value and divides flat rate to get correct value. Only thing that bothers me is that it's not rounding so I get 159.99 instad of 160, will check where conversion is done to round it.

Answer (score 0):

can you please share the solution if you can. thanks!